# SQL Average of duration (h:mm:ss)

Tags: sql, average, duration

I'd like to take the average of serveral durations (h:mm:ss) using SQL.

So for instance

```
3:00:00
0:30:00
1:00:00
```

should average

```
1:30:00 -- (90min)
```

I tried CASTing in various formats with no success.

Thanks for any hint!

I tried CASTing in various formats (float and datetime) with no success.

Comment: You should use TIME_TO_SEC() to convert those times to seconds, then get the AVG() an after that use SEC_TO_TIME() to get the time again

Comment: What **DBMS** are you using. Always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS. Especially when it comes to dates, times and intervals, the DBMS differ a lot in what features and functions they offer. And what **data type** is the duration?

Comment: Why on earth would you think you need floating-point arithmetic for a duration?

Comment: What happens if you simply do `AVG(duration)`?

Comment: Thank you for the replies, sorry for the missing info (SQL noob writing): 

-This is for a personal project where I am playing around with an Excel on Google Sheets. The data type here is "number" (using TYPE, resulting in "1"), and the data format is "duration" (xx:xx:xx)

-Using Dbeaver (is that the DBMS?) on the downloaded CSV for the querries. I guess, if going for TIME_TO_SEC I would need to go for MySQL, right? 

-AVG(duration) results in a tiny decimal value, and departs from the H:MM:SS format

Comment: The data type is number, but the format is xx:xx:xx? How can that be? What number contains colons? That doesn't seem to make sense. Then, you have Excel, where you can insert formulas. But instead you are using DBeaver, a database tool? Why? It seems, I have no idea, what you are actually doing or trying to do. Sorry. Good luck, anyway.

Comment: @Thorsten try out yourself on google sheets: type 01:23:45 (or any duration) and Format as Number > Duration. Then check for =TYPE and let me know if its something other than 1 (=Number). And yes, I'm using Dbeaver for this and other SQL queries (3000+ rows in total, I only gave the three rows as an illustration) after importing the mentioned Excel. Please elaborate why I should not query in DBeaver, excited to hear your knowledable input...

Comment: Knowledgeable input? What I was trying to say is just that I lack knowledge here. You mentioned Excel on Google Sheets, so I supposed Excel. I never knew that Google had an Excel-like spreadsheet of their own. Just tried it. Mark the cells, click "Format" in the menu, go to "Number", choose "Time". Then go to the cell under your time data, choose "Functions", then "Average", mark the cells and you are done. So why the export to DBeaver and using SQL, when this is all about a single table that you can work on in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Hi Thorsten, as I said before this is for a personal (learning) project, to get familiar with different technologies in the beginner stage (Google Sheets, SQL, Tableau for the visualization part). Granted, this could all be done in Google Sheets / Excel by creating a pivot table / taking the average / adding a simple visualization. For this project I, however, 1.) only wanted to use Google Sheets / Excel for Data Cleaning, 2.) Use SQL / Dbeaver for summary statistics and analysis (for example, What is the average duration at location X before 10:00 am?), and use 3.) Tableau for Visualizations

Comment: Again, yes this can all be done using GSheets / Excel. The point is that I am trying to use several technologies to practice them. And SQL is in my opinion a lot faster if taking an average, while at the same time applying WHERE-filters. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not mentioned which DBMS. Here is the code which works in SQL Server.
First I converted the time into seconds and took the average. Later the result is converted back to time.

```
DECLARE @test AS TABLE (column1 TIME)

INSERT INTO @test SELECT '3:00:00'
INSERT INTO @test SELECT '0:30:00'
INSERT INTO @test SELECT '1:00:00'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(SECOND,AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0,column1)),0),108) FROM @test
```

Answer (score 0):

### MySQL:

If you have a table where you store durations you can simply do this to get the average of the durations.

Example:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(
        SEC_TO_TIME(
            AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(duration))
        ) AS CHAR
    ) AS average_duration
FROM durations;
```